# Gradle and slf4j / logback

Tags: gradle, logback, slf4j

Is it possible to redirect Gradle logs to slf4j/logback.

I know you can use a custom SLF4J logger https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html#sec:sending_your_own_log_messages, but where should the `logback.properties` should sit?

Also, besides your messages can you redirect all Gradle messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the rules for loading config in the logback documentation here https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Specifically:

> 1. Logback tries to find a file called logback-test.xml in the classpath.
> 2. If no such file is found, logback tries to find a file called logback.groovy in the classpath.
> 3. If no such file is found, it checks for the file logback.xml in the classpath..

Comment: How can I add such a file or its parent folder to the classpath?

Comment: And how can I change the binding for SLF4J in the Gradle project? Currently it is `org.gradle.internal.logging.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext`.